# How can i pass data between two classes, components in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two classes. I want to pass data from one class to another. How can I achieve that?

```
class A extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <B  data={this.getData()} />
    );
  }
}


class B extends React.Component {
    //How can i consume "data" in here?
}
```

Comment: This is possibly the most basic part of React. Please follow the [tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) and search the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) first.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the data in class B using:

```
this.props.data
```

Comment: Take a look at the React documentation for further understanding on passing props through components:

https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 0):

Your `B` component will be given a prop called `data` which you can access with `this.props.data` within your `B` component.

https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#passing-data-through-props

```
class A extends React.Component {
  getData() {
    return [ { "test": "data" } ];
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <B  data={this.getData()} />
    );
  }
}


class B extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <label>test: <span>{this.props.data['test']}</span></label>
    );

}
```